# Oracle query to find one to many relationship in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to query writing and need help to prepare a query in oracle . Here is the scenario, basically i need to find all the products where same product (col1)  assigned to multiple codes (col2). Table1 has huge records. For purpose of explaining i have provided a mock up data

Table1

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4
P1    B1   T1   I
P1    B1   T2   G
P1    B2   T1   I
P2    B3   T1   I
P2    B4   T2   I
P2    B5   T2   I
P6    B6   T1   I
P7    B7   T1   I
P8    B8   T2   I
```

Output expected is

```
P1   B1
P1   B2
P2   B3
P2   B4
P2   B5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(distinct col2) over (partition by col1) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Can this be done using  group by as well ?

Comment: Yes: select col1, col2 from t group by col1, col2 having count(*)>1

Comment: @oratom - that won't give the same result; only P1/B1 will be reported.

Comment: @Alex Poole- correct , i would need the output where col1 record has multiple relation with col2 as described in the expected output

Comment: @AlexPoole - ups, my mistake. I misunderstood the question. Gordon’s analytic approach is correct. Solutions with group by are far more complex and less efficient.

Comment: @oratom - yep, agreed, I've shown them for comparison but commented on performance. Analytics can hit memory problems though if there really is a huge amount of data - depends on your definition of 'huge' though *8-)

Answer (score 0):

An analytic query is probably the way to go, though it could cause problems with your huge data I suppose. You can't do a simple group by to get both values; getting just the `col1` value could be done with:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) > 1;
```

but that doesn't really help you. It could be used as a subquery though:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 in (
  select col1
  from t
  group by col1
  having count(distinct col2) > 1
)
order by col1, col2;
```

but now you have to hit the table twice, which might be more expensive than the analytic approach; and you would have to add `distinct` to get exactly the output you wanted.

You could also use a self-join of some kind, e.g. with `exists()`:

```
select col1, col2
from t t1
where exists (
  select null
  from t t2
  where t2.col1 = t1.col1
  and t2.col2 != t1.col2
)
order by col1, col2;
```

but again you'd need to check performance (and use `distinct`).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=806ec3b63f4cee3e25ec811a9e105f16) showing those, and @Gordon's analytic query for comparison (and @oratom's comment to show that doesn't do what you want).

Comment: I tried with the subquery and it worked and also with the analytic query (just added distinct on the columns which i needed). From performance wise the execution plan of analytic was better than the group by as you thought so . Thanks all for the advise.